# Delphi RAD Studio How to use CamelHumps Words Like Intellij IDEA?

Tags: delphi, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, camelcasing

I'm doing something with Delphi. However, I can't seem to figure out why RAD Studio doesn't support roaming trough my code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> on my CamelCase notation words. Eclipse and Intellij IDEA both support this feature but RAD Studio doesn't.

Are there any plugins, settings or keyboard shortcuts for this?

Comment: Well, different editors have different features. If you are missing an ability to move from one capital letter to the next one (within the same word), then that doesn't exist (AFAIK) in Delphis editor. Look in help for `Keyboard Mappings Index` for all shortcuts available in the various mappings available. Asking for recommendations (like plugins) is off topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could implement this yourself by writing an IDE add-in using OTA services.

Comment: Yes, this can easily be done using a keybinding package. One very simple example of such a keybinding package are my keybindings for those who have keyboards without an `INS` key: https://github.com/rvelthuis/INSlessKeyBindings. That replaces the Ctrl-Ins etc. shortcuts with Ctrl-C etc. and adds some extra key combos.

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio Code is an option. It has plug-ins for camelCase navigation as well as an excellent [add-in for Delphi](http://omnipascal.com/)